# Memory allocation Coregionalized Kernel

Tags: gpflow

I'm currently using a linear model of coregionalization
(see e.g. alvarez notes https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.6251.pdf )
which is optimized via SVGP.

I noticed that the upper limit of the number of inducing points before running OOM was greatly reduced (now about ~5k inducing points instead of 8k when not using a coregionalized kernel). From my understanding, the limiting bottleneck should have been the same (still the MxM kernel matrix), however it seems like more changed.

In addition, I now get the warning:

```
.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:112: UserWarning:

Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
```

The Kernel Matrices are constructed as follows.
I don't use big Qs or Rs (Q=3, R=3).

```
    def coreg_k(Q, R, output_dim, active_dims):
        # create Q different kernels with rank R
        coreg = []
        k_q = []

        # lengthscales = np.logspace(-1, 3, 5)
        lengthscales = [0.1, 1, 5]
        for q in range(Q):
            coreg_tmp = gpflow.kernels.Coregion(input_dim=1, output_dim=output_dim, rank=R, active_dims=active_dims)
            coreg_tmp.W = np.random.randn(output_dim, R)
            coreg.append(coreg_tmp)

            k_tmp = []
            k_tmp.append(Matern52(input_dim=len(kernel_idxs["coords"]), active_dims=kernel_idxs["coords"],
                                  lengthscales=lengthscales[q], ARD=False))
            k_tmp.append(RBF(input_dim=len(kernel_idxs["rest"]), active_dims=kernel_idxs["rest"],
                             ARD=True, lengthscales=lengthscales[q]))

            k = k_tmp[0]
            for i in range(1, len(k_tmp)):
                k += k_tmp[i]

            k_q.append(k)

        # combine all those kernels
        kern_lcm = coreg[0] * k_q[0]
        for q in range(1, Q):
            kern_lcm += coreg[q] * k_q[q]

        return kern_lcm
```

What is taking up so much memory? The few parameters more from the extra kernels should not change that much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the computation of the Kuu matrix, the coregionalisation kernel constructs an M x M matrix. So if you have Q `Coregion` kernels, tensorflow actually needs to allocate Q x M x M memory. This is not orders of magnitude more, but linear in the number of kernels, which seems to roughly match up with how much less inducing points you can fit in memory on your machine.

For a more efficient implementation of the intrinsic coregionalisation model, have a look at the [multi-output framework notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.ipynb) in the GPflow documentation. Hope this helps!